# Grails dynamic properties and patterns

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I am trying to develop a webapplication, but I can't think of the full design. The idea is the following:

I want to create a program with the possibility to create patterns which then can be used to create instances of the pattern. To make an example: We have funiture as patterns, so we have a name and different properties.
So the admin creates/deletes/edits the patterns: lets say "Chair" with "color" and "size" as properties and "Table" with "length", "color" and "size".

After that, the user could add "Tables" or "Chairs" with the properties you created first.

I have created Domain-Classes: User, Pattern, Property, Funiture
but I stuck with the relationship. I'm pretty sure grails is able to handle such requests but I'm not sure, if I'm on the right track.

Edit: More Specific:

I Have now a better idea of the whole construct:
domain-Classes (I'll skip the users for better understanding):
Pattern - Property - FurnitureProperties - Furniture

I know now, I need the "FurnitureProperties" to store the actual value of a created furniture. I'm a bit confused with the hasMany/belongsTo - Definitions of grails.

```
Pattern 
hasMany[properties:Property]
belongsTo [furniture:Furniture]

Property
hasMany [furnitureProperties: FurnitureProperties]
belongsTo [pattern:Pattern]

FurnitureProperties
(nothing, just Property and Furniture as fields)

Furniture
hasMany [furnitureProperties: FurnitureProperties]
belongsTo [pattern:Pattern]
```

I hope I can create patterns and properties which belong to that pattern and after that I can create new furniture, select a pattern, look up the Properties and create correct FurnitureProperties to fill them with specific Values. Would be like this:

```
Pattern: Chair and Table
Property: Chair.size, Chair.color / Table.width, Table.color
Furniture:Office-Chair, armchair, kitchen-table
furnitureProperty: all three furnitures with there properties depending on the pattern and the specific value.
```

Comment: Can you be more specific - what relationship are you stuck with? Are you unsure of how your domain classes might relate to each other generally, or is there a specific relationship that concerns you?

Comment: @Kelzama, did you find a solution or a Plugin for your case? I'm currently on a similar problem, but exaclty the other way: I need the domain class is built dynamically according the table's attributes, but only found a Plugin that creates DB schema dynamically from Grails:
[link]http://grails.org/plugin/dynamic-domain-properties Maybe this can help you.